# MVC submit isn't returning all data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm writing an MVC app which ends up accessing a SQL database. On my edit page, I previously had every item available to be edited that is in the model. Recently I was asked to no longer allow the user to edit the primary keys. I did a quick change to change the primary key fields (in this example, there are 2 of them) from an EditorFor to a DisplayFor. The new view is this:

```
@model App.Data.Item
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}

<h2>Edit</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Item</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        <div class="form-group">
            <strong>ID:</strong>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <p>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ID)</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <strong>ID2:</strong>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <p>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ID2)</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <strong>Description:</strong>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <p>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Description)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description)</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <br />
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit <i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

It used to work with the full editing. Now the data is displayed properly, as expected. However, when submit is pressed, Null values are passed back to the controller for the values that are displayed.

These are the edit functions in my controller. ItemService.Edit() just saves the data to the server. It works correctly.

```
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult Edit(string id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            //return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        string[] vals = id.Split('|');
        ItemAttribute itemAttribute = itemAttributeService.Find(int.Parse(vals[0]), vals[1]);
        if (itemAttribute == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(itemAttribute);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "ID,ID2,Description")] 
        Item item)
    {
        if (item.Description == null)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("Description", "Description cannot be null.");
        }
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            itemService.Edit(item);
            return RedirectToAction("../Home/Index/");
        }
        return View(item);
    }
```

Lastly, my data model:

```
public class Item
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string ID2 { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Why is the data no longer being passed back to the second function, and how do I get it to pass correctly so that I can save it to the database?

Comment: Include hidden fields using `@Html.HiddenFor()` so they post back, or better create a view model with just the properties you want to edit, then when you post back, get the data model and update it based on the properties of the view model. Note you don't need the `Bind` attribute

Comment: Thanks I wasn't aware of HiddenFor. Also, I thought I would need bind. What is it for then?

Comment: In you case you are posting back and wanting to bind all properties. You would only use `Bind` of you wanted to bind to only a few of the properties you posted back so if you used `[Bind(Include = "ID,ID2")]` then whatever was posted back for `Description` would be ignored and not bound to your model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have an input element generated for the items that you want returned.  Currently, you are only displaying two of your model elements and have no associated input with them.  As a result, they will not be POSTed back to the server.

To get them to post to the server and not "editable" from a textbox, add a `Html.HiddenFor()` helper for each of the items that you need returned.

```
   <div class="form-group">
        <strong>ID:</strong>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <p>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ID)</p>
            <p>@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ID)</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <strong>ID2:</strong>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <p>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ID2)</p>
            <p>@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ID)</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

However, keep in mind that anyone can edit the HTML using Firebug or Chrome console tools and submit any value that they want for any field, even if you did not want to change it.  Be sure that when you are persisting the changes to the database, you are **NOT** including these fields as part of the update.

Comment: Thank you. I was unaware of HiddenFor.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, just before this line of code:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ID)
```

put in this for debugging:

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.ID)
```

Tell us what you see...

If you see the label then check your controller, in particular the parameter it takes on the post.  It should take and Item of type ITEM per your model.

Before the controller receives the data MVC has to try to populate the data... It converts name/value pairs to model types with values secretly.  If you don't see any data after you are in the controller it's usually because the names were not found!

Comment: This is not an answer.  If you need more information, use the comment section below the question.

Comment: I wanted to use the formatting option not available in comments to help the user.  No it's not an answer it's a debug point that will lead to the answer.  Thoughts?

Comment: I didn't tie in the fact that DisplayFor will not post back.  Rather I was tryin to track whether or not the property was even binding in the view.  I've miss-used the "For" properties myself in the past and have lost data on post back.